# Set dynamic date on google calander

Tags: date, dynamic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iK3z.png)I am using google calendar .net mvc  to show the total work time in resource section. How can calendar day view dynamic set next date if total time exceed 24 hr. please see attached.

Comment: It seems that you forget to attach your document.

Comment: please see the doc now.